# Pyforms web sample now working, only django's default site showing up

Tags: django, python-3.x, pyforms

I'm trying to follow along with the example shown here: https://pyforms-web.readthedocs.io/en/v4/getting-started/first-app.html to get the first app running.

The [Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMoQZ.jpg) of the default Django app looks like that.

I added the code as in the example, ran migrate and opened the brower, but only the default Django page shows up.

My site_crawl.py looks like this:

```
from pyforms.basewidget import BaseWidget
from confapp import conf

        class SiteCrawlApp(BaseWidget):

              UID                  = 'site-crawl-app'
              TITLE                = 'Site crawl'

              LAYOUT_POSITION      = conf.ORQUESTRA_HOME

              ORQUESTRA_MENU       = 'left'
              ORQUESTRA_MENU_ICON  = 'browser'
              ORQUESTRA_MENU_ORDER = 0
```

The settings.py looks like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'project',
 ]
```

Those are the only changes I made to the default structure created when I ran `django-admin startproject project` also ran `python manage.py migrate` before starting the web server with `python manage.py runserver`.

I'm using Python 3.6.0, Django 2.1.7 and Pyforms v4.

Can somebody help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jose, welcome to StackOverflow.  Could you please edit into the question the code *you* are using?  And perhaps describe exactly what "ran migrate" means?

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my post to add more details, hope it helps!

Comment: 1. Your app code does not have the correct indentation. 2. You did not set the correct configurations in your settings.py file. Follow the instructions here: https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/projects/Pyforms-WEB/en/v4/getting-started/installing.html